# Lombok's @Builder and Javadoc Creation

Tags: java, lombok

In one of my projects, I'm handling some POJOs that may have 20+ fields. I'm using the Builder Pattern to make object creation less cumbersome. Lombok's `@Builder` annotation really removes a lot of boilerplate code and speeds up my process. Thing is that **I want to add Javadoc to the 'setter'-like methods** in the various builders of my project. I've tried to put the Javadoc to the fields just like Lombok's [recommendation](https://www.projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) on `@Getter/@Setter` but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any possible method to achieve what I want?

Comment: [This ticket over at github](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2481) seems to address the issue. It was closed recently. I would expect that the fix will be in the next release of lombok.

Comment: @Turing85 Nice catch. Guess I'll have to wait until the next release. I will continue as if the issue doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use @Accessors(chain = true) instead of @Builder.

Your Getter and Setter will return your instance and you can also use Method-Chaining like in Builder Pattern.

The syntax will be like

```
Model model = new Model().setId(23L).setTitle("test");
```

We always use this instead of @Builder.

Lomboks recommendation should work with this solution

Comment: Interesting solution. This seems a nice way to go although 2 things are holding me: 1) refactoring of every class (which are more than 50) not to mention the unit test refactors and 2) that is experimental although it has a positive status. Nevertheless, if @Turing85 above didn't mention that lombok's team are actively trying to solve the exact issue I have , you would have put me in serious thoughts. +1

Comment: We are using it in several projects for years on production :-) 
Never had problems with it.
But - we had a few problems with @Builder instead!
I also like the syntax more that builder syntax.

Comment: Maybe next project will have that method applied! Didn't even know @Accessors

Comment: This will be flawed when you are extending a super class. The setter of the super class will return the super class. I would stick with `Builder` (or `SuperBuilder`).

Comment: @JasperdeVries , yes you are right. In case of inheritance I would not stick to Accessors.
Its now 1,5 years ago - Lombok did a lot since then. There is also a new? `With` annotation which also still experimental like `Builder` but also promoted. Maybe it's worth to have a look at it.